# Indefinite integral that Wolfram Alpha can't solve

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals, wolfram-alpha, symbolic-computation

Does anybody know the indefinite integral problems that Wolfram Alpha can not solve but human can solve by using elementary functions?

(The meaning of "solve" here is to represent　primitive function by using elementary functions.)

Comment: $\displaystyle \int\frac{1}{\sqrt[4]{1+x^4}}dx$ and $\displaystyle \int\frac{1}{\sqrt[4]{x^4-1}}dx$

Comment: The former can not be represent by elementary function. It needs elleptic functions.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Risch_algorithm#Problem_examples

Comment: Since there seem to be confusion below, I just want to mention that the first integral suggested by @juantheron are given by $\frac12\bigl(\arctan(x/(1+x^4)^{1/4})+\text{artanh}\,(x/(1+x^4)^{1/4})\bigr).$ The second one is $\frac12\bigl(\arctan(x/(x^4-1)^{1/4})+\text{artanh}\,(x/(x^4-1)^{1/4})\bigr).$

Comment: Sites like these https://www.integral-calculator.com/ are still able to solve this, no elliptic integrals necessary.  Try it out if you don’t believe me.  Use root(4,...) or (...)^(1/4) in place of ⁴√(...).

Comment: @juantheron I also find it rather interesting that for any integer n, the integral of 1/nroot(x^n±1) has an elementary solution.

Answer (score 7):

*Mathematica* (and by extension, Wolfram Alpha), has a hard time with integrands that are amenable to substitutions of the form $u = x^k \pm x^{-k}$ for positive integers $k$.  So for example, $$\int \frac{1-x^4}{(1+x^2+x^4)\sqrt{1+x^4}} \, dx = \tan^{-1} \frac{x}{\sqrt{1+x^4}} + C$$ but *Mathematica* (as of v9) will give a result in terms of elliptic functions.  As an aside, I recommend trying to prove the above equation as it is quite instructive.

---

In fact, just by computing derivatives of $$F(x) = \tan^{-1} \frac{x^m}{\sqrt{1+x^n}}$$ for various positive integer choices of $m, n$, and then simplifying the result, you can obtain integrands of the form $$f(x) = F'(x) = \frac{(2m + (2m-n) x^n) x^{m-1}}{2(1+x^n+x^{2m})\sqrt{1+x^n}}$$ whose antiderivatives are not known to *Mathematica*, and probably not to other computer algebra programs; e.g., try $(m,n) = (3,7)$ or even $(m,n) = (13, 59)$.

Comment: doesn't the OP want the fourth root, not the second root?

Comment: @JackLam The original post said nothing about the required form of the integrand, only that it should have an elementary closed-form antiderivative which cannot be found through Wolfram Alpha.

Comment: I see. Does the OP's two commented problems have elementary closed-form antiderivatives?

Comment: The comment was not made by the same user who asked the original question.  I suspect those integrals do not have elementary closed-form antiderivatives but I do not have a proof of this claim.

Comment: @heropup These are doable in elementary functions, see my comment.

Comment: By the way, axiom manage your first integral and also your second with $(m,n)=(3,7)$. I have not tried the general one...

Answer (score 4):

Interestingly, Alpha seems unaware of the floor function $\lfloor x\rfloor$ for which a continuous antiderivative can be found.

$$\int \lfloor x\rfloor dx=\lfloor x\rfloor\left(x-\frac{\lfloor x\rfloor+1}2\right)+C.$$

Comment: It’s kinda weird, to integrate functions like that requires use of discrete calculus.  In this case, the function is flat for most x values, so your function is just x times y, but then you have to add another flat function to keep it continuous, which often requires taking the antidifference (indefinite sum) of another function.  In this case, it’s xy minus the floor(x)th triangle number, as in the indefinite sum of floor(x).

Comment: @MathMachine: sorry, can't make sense of the relevance of your comment.

Comment: The relevance is for a computer to integrate a function like that would require it to utilize an entirely different branch of calculus, thus requiring many, many extra lines of code for a few functions people don’t integrate very frequently.  For instance, try to integrate floor(√(x)).  It is possible, but it requires some math that is probably unfamiliar territory.  I’d be all for someone making a calculator that could do all that, but I can understand it being at its limits when you get to that point.

Comment: "an entirely different branch of calculus": this is just a piecewise constant function. By the way, Alpha has no problem computing the definite integrals.

Comment: Of course it has no problem doing definite integrals with specific constants as the endpoints, but it won't do definite integrals with $a$ and $b$ as the endpoints. Like the indefinite integral, this would require it to think outside the box.

Answer (score 1):

WA resorts to complex variables for less familiar integrals. For instance, it evaluates the integral below as
\begin{align}
&\int \cot^{-1}(1+x^2)\ dx \\
=&\ x\cot^{-1}(x^2+1)+2\bigg( \frac{\tan^{-1}\frac x{(1-i)^{1/2}}}{(1-i)^{3/2}}
 + \frac{\tan^{-1}\frac x{(1+i)^{1/2}}}{(1+i)^{3/2}} \bigg)
\end{align}

while its elementary anti-derivative is
\begin{align}
&\int \cot^{-1}(1+x^2)\ dx \\
=&\ x\cot^{-1}(1+x^2)
+\sqrt{2(\sqrt{2}-1)}\tan^{-1}\frac{x^2-\sqrt{2}}{x\sqrt{2(\sqrt{2}+1)}} \\
& \>\>\>\>\>\>\>\>\>\>\>\>\>\>\>- \sqrt{2(\sqrt{2}+1)}\tanh^{-1}\frac{x^2+\sqrt{2}}{x\sqrt{2(\sqrt{2}-1)}}
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

[Wolfram Alpha (nor Mathematica)](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=integrate%20%28%281-tan%28%28arcsecx%29%2F2%29%29%2F%20%281%2Btan%28%28arcsecx%29%2F2%29%29%20%29*sqrt%28tan%28%28arccscx%29%2F2%29%29%20&lang=es) is unable to solve the following integral:

> $$\int \frac{{1 - \tan\frac12\sec^{-1}x}}{{1 + \tan\frac12\sec^{-1}x}}\sqrt{\tan\frac12\csc^{-1}x} \,dx.\tag{1}$$

[Neither this one](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=integrate%20lnxsqrttan%28arccscx%2F2%29%20&lang=es):

> $$\int \ln{x} \sqrt{\tan\frac12\csc^{-1}x} \, dx.\tag{2}$$

However, thanks to this **[*new trick*](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/463459/identities-that-simplify-tedious-integrals)**, we can solve them (just like many other 'impossible' related integrals).

Comment: Do not post identical, or near identical, answers to multiple questions.  If one answer correctly answers more than one question, answer *at most* one of those questions, and flag the rest as duplicates.